# Creating combinations of multiple columns into object of array consisting of combination of values & column name in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8

Creating combinations of multiple columns into object of array consisting of combination of values & column name in java ?
So that each object will consist of array of `Object (column name, value)`.

I've information stored by it's column name & values inside that column.
For example:

```
Region  Store       State
west    Reliance    california
east    Dmart       newyork
```

Basically for above the JSON structure is as below

```
[
  {
    "type": "Region",
    //more fields
    "filterValues": [
      {
        "name": "west"
        //more fields
      },
      {
        "name": "east"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Store",
    "filterValues": [
      {
        "name": "Reliance"
      },
      {
        "name": "Dmart"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "State",
    "filterValues": [
      {
        "name": "california"
      },
      {
        "name": "newyork"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How I can convert the above structure into the following combinations:

```
Region west  | Store Reliance | State california
Region west  | Store Reliance | State newyork
Region west  | Store Dmart    | State california
Region west  | Store Dmart    | State newyork
.
.
.
```

So the Object structure will be as follow.

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "type": "Region",
        "name": "west"
      },
      {
        "type": "Store",
        "name": "Reliance"
      },
      {
        "type": "State",
        "name": "california"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "type": "Region",
        "name": "west"
      },
      {
        "type": "Store",
        "name": "Reliance"
      },
      {
        "type": "State",
        "name": "newyork"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I do implement this data structure ?
I was trying by creating map first in which column name will be `key` & values in that column will be part of `value` as

```
Map<String, List<String>> typeBOsMap = attributes
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Attribute::getType,
                                attribute -> attribute.getFilterValues()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(AttributeFilters::getFilterValue)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        );
```

But after this again I'm stuck at how the combination will get created from this map ?

---

Comment: there is always three types or can be multiple ?

Comment: There can be multiple types. It’s dynamic. 1/2/3 or more.

Comment: A way is using recursion. Recursively go for type and iterate the type value and add in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert `typeBOsMap` into `List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>`

```
  List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> list = typeBOsMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then recursive permute all possible combination

```
  List<List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> permute(List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> list,
      int index, List<Map.Entry<String, String>> now) {
    if (index >= list.size()) {
      return Arrays.asList(now);
    }
    Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry = list.get(index);
    List<List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
      List<Map.Entry<String, String>> newList = new ArrayList<>(now);
      newList.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), value));
      res.addAll(permute(list, index + 1, newList));
    }
    return res;
  }
```

You can call this function using `list`

```
List<List<Map.Entry<String, String>>> data = permute(list, 0, Collections.emptyList());
```

Output:

```
[State=california, Region=west, Store=Reliance]
[State=california, Region=west, Store=Dmart]
[State=california, Region=east, Store=Reliance]
[State=california, Region=east, Store=Dmart]
[State=newyork, Region=west, Store=Reliance]
[State=newyork, Region=west, Store=Dmart]
[State=newyork, Region=east, Store=Reliance]
[State=newyork, Region=east, Store=Dmart]
```

Online Demo [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJL2FqBfD)

Comment: Did you try this solution ?  Feel free to ask if you have any question ?

Comment: This is kickass. Exactly what I wanted.  Later in code I just did `stream.map(-> construct object)`. while constructing object I also iterate on `inner map` to get `key,values`. 
I think function name should be renamed to `combine`, what say ?

Comment: That totally depends on personal taste.